# connect to db mysql in go

Tags: mysql, go

I am currently working oin a project in go. I need to connect to mysql db and do some stuff. Currently, i am having trouble with the connection.

First, i load and store the db crdentials from various possible sources (CLI, config file or startup parameter, depending on situation)

```
dbCredentials = DatabaseCredentials{DRIVER_NAME,BOT_LOGIN_NAME + ":" + BOT_PASSWORD + "@tcp(" + HOST_NAME + ")/" + NAME_OF_DB}
```

Later i try to open the connection:

```
db, err := sql.Open(dbCredentials.driverName, dbCredentials.dataSourceName) 
checkErr(err)
defer db.Close()
```

But i always get 
Error 1045: Access denied for user 'bot'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

The weird thing is the very same section of code used to work a couple of days ago and i am not aware of any changes that could cause this behaviour. I also didnt make any changes on the database.

Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong? Some input regarding what to look at for finding the error would be helpful.

Comment: Flush mysql privileges and grant permissions to your Bot user. Try to login to mysql shell using same configurations see If it works or give same error

Comment: Doesn't seem like a problem in your Go code: it connects to the database server just fine. The error message is very self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has disappeared as mysteriously as it appeared.